# Writing accented characters from user input to a text file Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.7, python-unicode

Hello I have the following code snippet:

```
while True:   
    try:
        entry = input("Input element: ")
        print (entry)
        with open(fileName,'a',encoding='UTF-8') as thisFile:
           thisFile.write(entry)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
       break
```

This one basically continuously gets input and writes it to a file until manually interrupted. However, when the user inputs something like a Ñ. It outputs: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: surrogates not allowed` I explicity put the utf-8 encoding and even tried latin-1 but still the same error. I have also put the `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` on top of my code and tried `thisFile.write(entry.encode('utf-8')` but it still gives me the error.

Comment: Are you doing this in Idle?

Comment: I'm using vscode as my editor. I even set the unicode from vscode at the bottom right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the following environment variables fixed it for me.

```
export LANG=C.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
```

or another method is running it via:
`PYTHONIOENCODING="UTF-8" python3 writetest.py`